# Should 'deceptive' training cases be given to a Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, training-data, naivebayes

I am setting up a Naive Bayes Classifier to try to determine sameness between two records of five string properties. I am only comparing each pair of properties exactly (i.e., with a java .equals() method). I have some training data, both TRUE and FALSE cases, but let's just focus on the TRUE cases for now.

Let's say there are some TRUE training cases where all five properties are different. That means every comparator fails, but the records are actually determined to be the 'same' after some human assessment.

Should this training case be fed to the Naive Bayes Classifier? On the one hand, considering the fact that NBC treats each variable separately these cases shouldn't totally break it. However, it certainly seems true that feeding in enough of these cases wouldn't be beneficial to the classifier's performance. I understand that seeing a lot of these cases would mean better comparators are required, but I'm wondering what to do in the time being. Another consideration is that the flip-side is impossible; that is, there's no way all five properties could be the same between two records and still have them be 'different' records.

Is this a preferential issue, or is there a definitive accepted practice for handling this?

Comment: It seems to me that a learning algorithm should only be applied in cases where it has the capability of making the correct distinction. If there are TRUE cases that the algorithm is not able to detect then as you said, it should be improved. If the issue arises from human input, you can try standardizing it by removing all special characters and changing all letters to upper or lower case. You can also use a more nuanced comparison and try to pull out common typos or spelling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will want to have a training data set that is as feasibly representative as possible of the domain from which you hope to classify observations (often difficult though). An unrepresentative set may lead to a poorly functioning classifier, particularly in a production environment where various data are received. That being said, preprocessing may be used to limit the exposure of a classifier trained on a particular subset of data, so it is quite dependent on the purpose of the classifier.

I'm not sure why you wish to exclude some elements though. Parameter estimation/learning should account for the fact that two different inputs may map to the same output --- that is why you would use machine learning instead of simply using a hashmap. Considering that you usually don't have 'all data' to build your model, you have to rely on this type of inference.

Have you had a look at the  [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/); it is in python but it seems that [OpenNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478263/java-equivalent-for-python-nltk) may be a suitable substitute in Java? You can employ better  feature extraction techniques that lead to a model that accounts for minor variations in input strings (see [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html)).

Lastly, it seems to me that you want to learn a mapping from input strings to the classes '*same*' and '*not same'* --- you seem to want to infer a distance measure (just checking). It would make more sense to invest effort in directly finding a better measure (e.g. for character transposition issues you could use [edit distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)). I'm not sure that NB is well-suited to your problem as it is attempting to determine a class given an observation(s) (or its features). This class will have to be discernible over various different strings (I'm assuming you are going to concatenate string1 & string2, and offer them to the classifier). Will there be enough structure present to derive such a widely applicable property? This classifier is basically going to need to be able to deal with all pair-wise 'comparisons' ,unless you build NBs for each one-vs-many pairing. This does not seem like a simple approach.